# QlikView "field not found" workaround for adding a new field

Tags: field, qlikview

I am trying to get my script to reload in QlikView without success. I have added a new field (named `Litres`) to my most recently generated QVD files. However, my older QVD files do not have this `Litres` field which therefore causes the script to error out with the "Field not found" error.

I am trying to do the following:

- Search for all the fields in the QVD
- If the `Litres` field exists, then load the data into QlikView.
- If not, create the field with a value of zero and continue.

The above should not result in an error.

**My current script is below:**

```
/* get all sales csvs */
sales:
load 2014 as Year 
AutoGenerate 0;

set FilePath = ..\..\SourceData\qv-sales*.csv;

for each File in filelist('$(FilePath)')

/* load qvd file if it is newer than csv file */


  temptable1:
    first 1 LOAD           
    *
    FROM $(File)
    (txt, codepage is 1252, embedded labels, delimiter is ',', msq);

   IF FieldNumber('Litres' , 'temptable1') <> null then

  SET  "Litres";
  SET  "Litres LY" ;
  SET dyncode2 = P-Value;
  SET dyncode3 = O-P-Value;
  SET dyncode4 = P-Value LY;
  SET dyncode5 = O-P-Value LY;
  SET dyncode6 = P-Qty;
  SET dyncode7 = P-O-Qty;
  SET dyncode8 = P-Qty LY;
  SET dyncode9 = P-O-Qty LY;




ENDIF;



 DROP TABLE temptable1; 


   let qvdFile = replace('$(File)','csv','qvd');

   if (QvdCreateTime('$(qvdFile)') >= FileTime('$(File)')) then

       /* load qvd file if it is newer than csv file */
       sales:
       Concatenate (sales) load

         "GP",
         "O-GP",
         "Litres",
         "Litres LY",
         "GP LY",
         "O-GP LY",
         $(dyncode2) as "P-Value",
         $(dyncode3) as "O-P-Value",
         $(dyncode4) as "P-Value LY",
         $(dyncode5) as "O-P-Value LY",
         $(dyncode6) as "P-Qty",
         $(dyncode7) as "P-O-Qty",
         $(dyncode8) as "P-Qty LY",
         $(dyncode9) as "P-O-Qty LY" from $(qvdFile) (qvd);


   else

        /* create temp store key1 & key2 are manually handled synthetic keys */
        /* Dummy field is to prevent autoconcatenation problems.             */
       temptable:
       noconcatenate Load 

         "GP",
         "O-GP",
         "Litres" ,
         "Litres LY",
         "GP LY",
         "O-GP LY",
         $(dyncode2) as "P-Value",
         $(dyncode3) as "O-P-Value",
         $(dyncode4) as "P-Value LY",
         $(dyncode5) as "O-P-Value LY",
         $(dyncode6) as "P-Qty",
         $(dyncode7) as "P-O-Qty",
         $(dyncode8) as "P-Qty LY",
         $(dyncode9) as "P-O-Qty LY",

         autonumber(1) as dummy1  
       FROM $(File) (ansi, txt, delimiter is ',', embedded labels); 

        /* create qvd file from temp table */
        if (ScriptErrorCount = 0) then
          Store temptable into $(qvdFile);
      endif

        sales:
        concatenate("sales") load

         "Litres",
         "Litres LY",
         "GP LY",
         "O-GP LY"  
         "P-Value",
         "O-P-Value",
         "P-Value LY",
         "O-P-Value LY",
         "P-Qty",
         "P-O-Qty",
         "P-Qty LY",
         "P-O-Qty LY" 
         resident temptable;

        /* drop temp table */

          DROP TABLE temptable;

   endif

next File
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FieldNumber` function to determine whether a field exists in a table. For example `FieldNumber('MyField', 'MyTable')` returns the position of `MyField` within `MyTable`. If `MyField` does not exist in `MyTable` the function returns zero.

You can adapt this to your advantage by loading all fields from your QVD into a temporary table and then  checking to see if this table contains the field. If it does, you can continue loading. If not, you can simply set the field to zero.

I have adapted your script and inserted an IF for this purpose:

```
/* get all sales csvs */
sales:
load 2014 as Year 
AutoGenerate 0;

set FilePath = ..\..\SourceData\qv-sales*.csv;

for each File in filelist('$(FilePath)')

    /* load qvd file if it is newer than csv file */   
    temptable1:
    first 1 LOAD           
        *
    FROM $(File)
    (txt, codepage is 1252, embedded labels, delimiter is ',', msq);

    IF FieldNumber('Litres' , 'temptable1') <> null then
        SET  "Litres";
        SET  "Litres LY" ;
        SET dyncode2 = P-Value;
        SET dyncode3 = O-P-Value;
        SET dyncode4 = P-Value LY;
        SET dyncode5 = O-P-Value LY;
        SET dyncode6 = P-Qty;
        SET dyncode7 = P-O-Qty;
        SET dyncode8 = P-Qty LY;
        SET dyncode9 = P-O-Qty LY;
    ENDIF

DROP TABLE temptable1; 

let qvdFile = replace('$(File)','csv','qvd');

if (QvdCreateTime('$(qvdFile)') >= FileTime('$(File)')) then

    /* load qvd file if it is newer than csv file */
    fieldcheck:
    FIRST 1
    NOCONCATENATE
    LOAD
        *
    FROM $(qvdFile) (qvd);

    if FieldNumber('Litres','fieldcheck') = 0 then

        drop table fieldcheck;

        sales:
        Concatenate (sales) load
        "GP",
        "O-GP",
        0 as "Litres",
        0 as "Litres LY",
        "GP LY",
        "O-GP LY",
        $(dyncode2) as "P-Value",
        $(dyncode3) as "O-P-Value",
        $(dyncode4) as "P-Value LY",
        $(dyncode5) as "O-P-Value LY",
        $(dyncode6) as "P-Qty",
        $(dyncode7) as "P-O-Qty",
        $(dyncode8) as "P-Qty LY",
        $(dyncode9) as "P-O-Qty LY" from $(qvdFile) (qvd);

    else

        drop table fieldcheck;

        sales:
        Concatenate (sales) load
        "GP",
        "O-GP",
        "Litres",
        "Litres LY",
        "GP LY",
        "O-GP LY",
        $(dyncode2) as "P-Value",
        $(dyncode3) as "O-P-Value",
        $(dyncode4) as "P-Value LY",
        $(dyncode5) as "O-P-Value LY",
        $(dyncode6) as "P-Qty",
        $(dyncode7) as "P-O-Qty",
        $(dyncode8) as "P-Qty LY",
        $(dyncode9) as "P-O-Qty LY" from $(qvdFile) (qvd);

    endif

else
        /* create temp store key1 & key2 are manually handled synthetic keys */
        /* Dummy field is to prevent autoconcatenation problems.             */
       temptable:
       noconcatenate Load 

         "GP",
         "O-GP",
         "Litres" ,
         "Litres LY",
         "GP LY",
         "O-GP LY",
         $(dyncode2) as "P-Value",
         $(dyncode3) as "O-P-Value",
         $(dyncode4) as "P-Value LY",
         $(dyncode5) as "O-P-Value LY",
         $(dyncode6) as "P-Qty",
         $(dyncode7) as "P-O-Qty",
         $(dyncode8) as "P-Qty LY",
         $(dyncode9) as "P-O-Qty LY",

         autonumber(1) as dummy1  
       FROM $(File) (ansi, txt, delimiter is ',', embedded labels); 

        /* create qvd file from temp table */
        if (ScriptErrorCount = 0) then
          Store temptable into $(qvdFile);
      endif

        sales:
        concatenate("sales") load

         "Litres",
         "Litres LY",
         "GP LY",
         "O-GP LY"  
         "P-Value",
         "O-P-Value",
         "P-Value LY",
         "O-P-Value LY",
         "P-Qty",
         "P-O-Qty",
         "P-Qty LY",
         "P-O-Qty LY" 
         resident temptable;

        /* drop temp table */

          DROP TABLE temptable;

   endif

next File
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct you need to regenerate your QVDs because you added a new field which doesn't exists in the previous ones, so you recreate them from the source (txt) and store them.
A simpler way to achieve this is to take advantage of the fact that when you do a [forced concatenate](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2020/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/LoadData/concatenate-tables.htm) with a table the missing fields will be generated with null, which we can use with the function [alt](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2020/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/ConditionalFunctions/alt.htm) to transform the null into 0.
so taking your example:

```
/* get all sales csvs */
sales:
load 2014 as Year 
AutoGenerate 0;

set FilePath = ..\..\SourceData\qv-sales*.csv;

for each File in filelist('$(FilePath)')
   let qvdFile = replace('$(File)','csv','qvd');

   //this generate the field Litres, exists or not
   tmp: noconcatenate load null() as Litres autogenerate(0);    

    if (QvdCreateTime('$(qvdFile)') >= FileTime('$(File)')) then    
        /* load qvd file if it is newer than csv file */
       concatenate(tmp) LOAD * FROM $(qvdFile) (qvd);
    else
       concatenate(tmp) LOAD * FROM $(File) 
       (txt, codepage is 1252, embedded labels, delimiter is ',', msq);
    endif;

    tmp_sales:
    noconcatenate
    load
        alt(Litres,0) as Litres,
        "Litres LY",
        "GP LY",
        "O-GP LY"  
        "P-Value",
        "O-P-Value",
        "P-Value LY",
        "O-P-Value LY",
        "P-Qty",
        "P-O-Qty",
        "P-Qty LY",
        "P-O-Qty LY" 
     resident tmp;
     drop table tmp;
    
     //if it was newer that the csv we store it
     if (QvdCreateTime('$(qvdFile)') >= FileTime('$(File)')) then 
         Store tmp_sales into $(qvdFile);
     endif

     concatenate(sales) load * resident tmp_sales;
     drop table tmp_sales;

next File
```